# Issue with sharing image and description via AddThis plugin in every social site

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, sharing, addthis

This is my code:

```
$('#sharethis').attr('addthis:url', "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "research_science/Details/" + returnedData.research_id);
$('#sharethis').attr('addthis:title', returnedData.research_name);
$('#sharethis').attr('addthis:description', returnedData.research_desc);
$('#sharethis').attr('addthis:media', "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + returnedData.research_logo);

addthis.update('share', 'url', "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "research_science/Details/" + returnedData.research_id);
addthis.update('share', 'title', returnedData.research_name);
addthis.update('share', 'description', returnedData.research_desc);
addthis.update('share', 'media', "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + returnedData.research_logo);
addthis.update('share', 'url', "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "research_science/Details/" + returnedData.research_id);

$(".addthis_toolbox .addthis_counter").replaceWith('<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>');
addthis.counter('.addthis_counter', null, {url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "research_science/Details/" + returnedData.research_id});
```

I used also used `og:image` property in header, but that works only for Facebook, not for other social site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Google, Facebook and twitter like all social website just read source
>   code of website. Social website not run your client-side js script;
>   **you need generate this type of tags in server side**(via PHP script).

Comment: Ok. For facebook I am using og:image for others?

Comment: add microdata in your website
Ref: http://schema.org/image
testing tool
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Comment: Ok. For now i just need for facebook only. Thanks a lot.